# Μeasuring the time of a thread quantum

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to measure the time each thread quantum takes using c#.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace pr
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        private static long t = 0;
        private static volatile int id = 0;
        private static BlockingCollection<long> deltas = new();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessAffinity();
            PriorityClass();
            ThreadDemo();
        }

        private static void ProcessAffinity()
        {
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)(1 << 0);
        }
    
        private static void PriorityClass()
        {
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime;
        }
    
        private static void ThreadDemo()
        {
            var thread1 = new Thread(() => InsideThread())
            {
                IsBackground = true,
                Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest
            };
            var thread2 = new Thread(() => InsideThread())
            {
                IsBackground = true,
                Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest
            };
    
            watch.Start();
            thread1.Start();
            thread2.Start();
            thread1.Join();
            thread2.Join();
    
            var avg = deltas.Average();
            Console.WriteLine("Average: " + avg);
            foreach (var e in deltas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("delta: " + e);
            }
        }
    
        private static void InsideThread()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var currentId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                Console.WriteLine("id" + currentId);
    
                if (id == 0)
                {
                    id = currentId;
                }
    
                if (id != currentId)
                {
                    var newt = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    deltas.Add(newt - t);
                    t = newt;
                    id = currentId;
                }
    
                if (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 3000) break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I print the id of the current thread to the console, everything kind of works and the delta gets counted. But the `Console.WriteLine` changes the context (I guess? I'm new in this topic) and increases the time, so the result is not correct (it's around 100 ms, while it's supposed to be around 32 ms). However, if I comment the `Console.WriteLine("id" + currentId);` out, the threads don't change: `thread2` seems to start only after `thread1` completes its work, so the final delta is 3000ms + something. Increasing the time doesn't help too. My question is: why don't the threads run simultaneously when `Console.WriteLine()` is commented out? How to measure the time of a thread quantum correctly? Should I use any locks? (I've tried, but nothing changed)

Comment: How do you define a "thread quantum"?

Comment: As far as I understand, a thread quantum is the amount of time a thread can run for before the thread scheduler lets another thread run

Comment: And you want to measure this amount of time in-thread? (Or at least get an estimate on it...)

Comment: I'm trying to keep track of the times when the thread is changed by checking its id and comparing it with the thread id stored in the static field. I'm doing it inside the threads, yes. I'm not sure how to do it outside the threads (if I understand the question correctly).

Comment: Why do you want to know this? I cannot see how it would be useful for anything, and if you are just curious this is information you can lookup this on the particular OS you are interested in.

Comment: JonasH it's a task from my university course. I know the result should be around 32 ms if the settings of the OS weren't changed

Comment: I am not even sure, you'll get a slightly correct estimate on that by measuring in-thread. Also, results will (if at all) probably only apply to that machine and OS. Also remember, .Net threads are _not necessarily_ OS-Threads. There may be a slight overhead caused by the runtime.

Comment: ^^ You may be more successful with analyzing [Performance Counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/performance-counters#lock-and-thread-performance-counters) ?? (Not sure)

Comment: Fildor, is there a way to measure that not in-thread?

Comment: I am not sure. I was just remembering performance counters and maybe they could be useful in getting more reliable measurements.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but the point is to calculate the time in-code. It doesn't really matter if the result is not very reliable, it only has to be around 32 ms for Windows 10

Comment: OK. So, in-thread it is ... harder than it sounds at first ...

Comment: pardon, so you're asking us to do your university homework? Then your question _isn't_ a real question.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono Being Homework is not enough to make a question off topic. OP tried something and realized it doesn't work as expected, so OP is asking for _hints towards doing it correctly_. He didn't ask to do the whole assignment for him. And it's a tricky one. So, that's OK for me.

Comment: Eriawan Kusumawardhonowell, I have nowhere else to go and ask for advice. I've tried to do it in many ways, but nothing seems to work and I'm stuck.

Comment: I hope we can somwhow summon one of the Gurus. This would be interesting to know.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Console.WriteLine will yield the time slice, possibly due to blocking on a lock. This is not really unexpected.

Without yielding, the `thread1` will have a higher priority than your "main" thread. So it is likely that `thread2.Start();` will never be run before the thread1 has completed.

To get around this you could use a [manualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim?view=net-6.0). Let each thread wait on the same event, and set this from the main thread after both have been started. Waiting on the event will block the threads, letting the main thread run. When the event has been set, both threads should be eligible to run.

Note that I'm not at all sure that this will give any accurate results, but it should fix the current behavior you are seeing.

Comment: ^^ I think Jonas is describing the actual hard part of this assignment: Making sure the measurements are actually meaningful.